# Gradient Ascent vs Gradient Descent in Logistic Regression

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, gradient-descent

I've been going trough Machine Learning in Action book from manning (https://www.manning.com/books/machine-learning-in-action) 
In the logistic regression chapter it uses gradient ascent to calculate the best weights.
Why do we pick gradient ascent instead of gradient descent ?

Comment: To find a maximum rather than a minimum.

Comment: I think the different rather reflects on engineering perspective, gradient descent always uses on a minimization setting that minimum is bounded somehow (for example negative log likelihood is bounded by 0).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent:

> To find a **local minimum** of a function using **gradient descent**,
>   one takes steps proportional to the negative of the gradient (or of
>   the approximate gradient) of the function at the current point.
>
> If instead one takes steps proportional to the positive of the
>   gradient, one approaches a **local maximum** of that function; the
>   procedure is then known as **gradient ascent**.

In other words:

- gradient *descent* aims at *minimizing* some objective function: $\theta_j \leftarrow \theta_j-\alpha \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_{j}} J(\theta)$
- gradient *ascent*  aims at *maximizing* some objective function: $\theta_j \leftarrow \theta_j+\alpha \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_{j}} J(\theta)$

Answer (score 10):

**What is a gradient?**

It is a derivative of a function at a certain point. Basically, gives the slope of the line at that point. How to calculate this slope geometrically(just consider a 2 D graph and any continuous function)? You draw a tangent at that point crossing x-axis and a perpendicular to the x-axis from that point. It will form a triangle and now calculating slope is easy. Also if this tangent is *parallel* to x-axis the *gradient is 0* and if it is *parallel* to y-axis the *gradient is infinity*.

**Why use ascent or  descent?**

If I have a function which is [convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) then at the bottom the *gradient* or *derivative* is 0. Similarly, if we have a [concave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function) function at the top *gradient* or *derivative* is 0. Why are we interested in 0? This is because it helps us find either the lowest(convex) or highest(concave) value of the function

Now our machine learning has a cost function and they can either be *concave* or *convex*. If it is *convex* we use ***Gradient Descent*** and if it is *concave* we use we use ***Gradient Ascent***. Now there are two cost functions for ***logistic regression***. When we use the convex one we use gradient descent and when we use the concave one we use gradient ascent. Also, note that if I add a minus before a convex function it becomes concave and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

@Franck is correct, they are the same thing other than the sign is positive or negative. There is good explanation in the book:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to minimize a function, we use Gradient Descent. For eg. in Deep learning we want to minimize the loss hence we use Gradient Descent.

If you want to maximize a function, we use Gradient Ascent. For eg. in Reinforcement Learning - Policy Gradient methods our goal is to maximize the reward function hence we use Gradient Ascent.